# iOS 9 runtime nop pit of death

Tags: ios, swift, realm, swift2

After upgrading to Swift 2.1, and adding Realm for Swift 2.1, I'm falling into what I'm calling the nop pit of death.  This occurs after my splash screen.

```
dyld_sim`dyld_fatal_error:
    0x106897000 <+0>: int3   
->  0x106897001 <+1>: nop
```

The splash screen hangs and I just sit here.  I'm not sure if this has anything to do with Realm or Swift 2.1, or any other dylibs.

I have tried to replace all of my dylib references in `Link Binary With Libraries` under `Build Phases` with their tbd's but that doesn't seem to do the trick either.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From the error message, it seems like, you didn't added `Realm.framework` (and `RealmSwift.framework`, if you don't mix Swift & Objective-C) to the *Embedded Binaries* pane, which you find in the *General* tab of your project, as shown below:

[image: Embedded Binaries]

For further validation, you can check the tab *Build Phases*. It should look like below:

[image: Build Phases]